# Yii framework 2.0 version vs 1.1.14

Tags: php, netbeans, yii

I am going to develop website by using Yii framework. I will use netbeans to do it (and if it will be possible) with build-in Yii plugin. And here is my dilemma: 
Should I use newest 2.0 version, which is demo version since yet, or use version 1.1.14, which is suported by my netbeans plugin. On official site of Yii I found quite good documentation for 2.0 version. Could you help me with some advices? Will be 1.1.14 version still suported be Yii community, could I use it without lot of painful searching for documentation or it would be better to stick with newest version?

Comment: most answers to questions about yii you can find exactly for yii 1.1.*, which have much more active community users than new yii 2.0 beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from their website: "Yii 2.0 is not ready for production use yet. It is currently under heavy development and we may introduce significant changes without prior notices. You may consider using Yii 2.0 if you just start to learn Yii or you do not have a tight project schedule."

They clearly are not encouraging using it in production in any way.

Answer (score 1):

2.0 version is bet yet... because of this I suggest you to use 1.14 stable version ... in real project always better to use stable versions

there is available 
[**Yii 1.1.15 is released (security fix)**](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/78/yii-1-1-15-is-released-security-fix/) as well

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on what the purpose of your Yii app is.

Are you building a quick demo? A throw away app? A 5 page app with no long-term maintainability needs? Go with Yii 1.1.15, it's very well documented and you will be able to work in a hurry.

Are you building a project with a minimum 3-5 year life? A web app that will see significant investment over the years? A web app that will have multiple developers involved in it? Go with Yii 2.0.

I've built large web apps with Yii 1.1.x and it works nicely. But for any significant new project, Yii 2.0 is a better fit. PHP as a language has progressed significantly since Yii 1.1 was designed and it shows.

In addition, development on Yii 1.1 *is* slowing down (the core team is more focused on Yii 2.0). I've for bug reports and pull requests for Yii 1.1 that have been outstanding for months. Not a slam on the core team (Yii 2.0 is where the future is), but Yii 1.1 is quickly going into maintenance mode.

Comment: I am not building big application and I am only person involved in it, it will be maybe only 8-pages website. So I will stick with 1.1.x. Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: @user2988670 Sounds good.  An accept would be much appreciated ;-)